# Fallacy change of variables in differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Consider the following differential equation:
$$
\frac{df(t)}{dt}=zf(t),
$$
for constant $z$. The solution yields
$$
f(t)=f(0)e^{zt}=f(0)e^{t'},
$$
with $t'=zt$. By taking the limit $t\rightarrow\infty$ and $z\rightarrow0$ keeping $t'$ constant:
$$
f(\infty)=f(0)e^{t'}.
$$
Let's call this "RESULT A".

On the other hand, by taking quadratures to transform the differential equation in an integral one:
$$
f(t)=f(0)+z\int_0^tf(s)ds.
$$
Now, let us change variables $t'=zt$ and $s'=zs$ then
$$
f(t'/z)=f(0)+\int_0^{t'}f(s'/z)ds'.
$$
By taking the limit $z\rightarrow0$ and $t\rightarrow\infty$ and $s\rightarrow\infty$ keeping finite both $t'$ and $s'$:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{z\rightarrow0}f(t'/z)&=&f(0)+\lim_{z\rightarrow0}\int_0^{t'}f(s'/z)ds'\\
f(\infty)&=&f(0)+\int_0^{t'} f(\infty) ds'=f(0)+ f(\infty) t'\\
f(\infty)&=&\frac{f(0)}{(1-t')}.
\end{eqnarray}
Let's call this "RESULT B".

Why RESULTS A and B are different?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in
$$ \lim_{z\to 0} \int_0^{t'} f(s'/z) \, ds', $$
you can't interchange the integral and the limit freely, because for $z$ large enough, there are always going to be places in the interval of integration where $s'/z \approx 1$ (and indeed a whole interval where it is much smaller than $1$).

(More formally, $f(s'/z)$ does not converge to $f(\infty)$ uniformly in $s'$ in the interval of integration, so the limit and the integral do not commute.)